# How do I add fixed value/symbol into an input field

Tags: java

https://i.stack.imgur.com/84fUa.png

I wanted to add a symbol into the respective input field as shown in the link (screenshot) above and make the symbol locked inside the JTextField and when the user type in something, the value must not overlap the symbol.

For instance when the user want to key in the annual interest rate, the text cursor should appear in front of the % symbol.

What code do I need to add in order to perform the said request.

This is my code:

```
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.border.TitledBorder;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

public class LoanCalculator extends JApplet {

    // Create text fields for interest rate, years
    // loan amount, monthly payment, and total payment
    private JTextField jtfAnnualInterestRate = new JTextField();
    private JTextField jtfNumberOfYears = new JTextField();
    private JTextField jtfLoanAmount = new JTextField();
    private JTextField jtfMonthlyPayment = new JTextField();
    private JTextField jtfTotalPayment = new JTextField();

    // Create a Compute Payment button
    private JButton jbtComputeLoan = new JButton("Compute Payment");

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Loan Payment Calculator");
        LoanCalculator applet = new LoanCalculator();
        frame.add(applet, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        applet.init();

        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null); // Center the frame
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setSize(320, 230);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public void init() {

        jtfMonthlyPayment.setEditable(false);
        jtfTotalPayment.setEditable(false);

        // Right align text fields
        jtfAnnualInterestRate.setHorizontalAlignment(JTextField.RIGHT);
        jtfNumberOfYears.setHorizontalAlignment(JTextField.RIGHT);
        jtfLoanAmount.setHorizontalAlignment(JTextField.RIGHT);
        jtfMonthlyPayment.setHorizontalAlignment(JTextField.RIGHT);
        jtfTotalPayment.setHorizontalAlignment(JTextField.RIGHT);

        // Panel p1 to hold labels and text fields
        JPanel p1 = new JPanel(new GridLayout(5, 2));
        p1.add(new JLabel("Annual Interest Rate : ", SwingConstants.RIGHT));
        p1.add(jtfAnnualInterestRate);
        p1.add(new JLabel("Number of Years : ", SwingConstants.RIGHT));
        p1.add(jtfNumberOfYears);
        p1.add(new JLabel("Loan Amount : ", SwingConstants.RIGHT));
        p1.add(jtfLoanAmount);
        p1.add(new JLabel("Monthly Payment : ", SwingConstants.RIGHT));
        p1.add(jtfMonthlyPayment);
        p1.add(new JLabel("Total Payment : ", SwingConstants.RIGHT));
        p1.add(jtfTotalPayment);
        p1.setBorder(new
                TitledBorder("Enter interest rate, year and loan amount"));

        // Panel p2 to hold the button
        JPanel p2 = new JPanel(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.RIGHT));
        p2.add(jbtComputeLoan);

        // Add the panels to the frame
        add(p1, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        add(p2, BorderLayout.SOUTH);

        // Register listener
        jbtComputeLoan.addActionListener(new ButtonListener());
    }

    /**
     * Handle the Compute Payment button
     */
    private class ButtonListener implements ActionListener {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            // Get values from text fields
            double interest =
                    Double.parseDouble(jtfAnnualInterestRate.getText());
            int year =
                    Integer.parseInt(jtfNumberOfYears.getText());
            double loanAmount =
                    Double.parseDouble(jtfLoanAmount.getText());

            // Create a loan object
            Loan loan = new Loan(interest, year, loanAmount);

            // Display monthly payment and total payment
            jtfMonthlyPayment.setText(String.format("%.2f",
                    loan.getMonthlyPayment()));
            jtfTotalPayment.setText(String.format("%.2f",
                    loan.getTotalPayment()));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can't you just put the % directly after the input box?

Comment: And how do I do that without using FlowLayout method? I know I can immitate that with FlowLayout but once window is resized, all the alignment will run. I'm trying to avoid that.

I know this is actually not really important as I just wanted to make the interface looks a bit better or more professional perhaps?

Answer (score 0):

How about setting the hint for the textfield? Take a look at this : [xswingx](https://code.google.com/p/xswingx/).

Comment: Your link *kind of* answers the question, but if you had a working code sample, that'd definitely boost this answer a bit.

Comment: I don't think this is what I wanted. This is more like a background text in the input field and will disappear when it is being focused. 

What I intend to do is more like inserting a small part of text with JLabel inside a JTextField itself. But I have no clue how to do that.